# Species Distribution Modeling with GAM: s() function giving weird summary results

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I'm using a GAM for a presence/absence species distribution model (SDM) from the `mgcv` package, where my n total = 125. At the moment, I'm getting some weird results, and I'm hoping to get some advice from someone who is more familiar with GAM than a neophyte like myself. My GAM equation is the following:

```
GAM1<-gam(final, data=sdmdata_final, family="binomial")
```

with `final` being the equation:

```
final<-pb~elev+p_jul+ndvi_1+ndvi_2+ndvi_3+t_sep+t_apr+t_feb+t_may+t_jun+t_total
```

The variables above are the environmental variables for the SDM, and `pb` is binomial data. Now, I understand that with a GAM, a smoothing function is typically used. In my case, I was initially using `s()` around each of my environmental variables, so the equation looked something like:

```
final.s<-pb~s(elev)+s(p_jul)+...+s(t_total)
```

However, when I entered `final.s` into the above GAM equation and performed a `summary(GAM1)`, I got an adjusted R-sq. = 1, with 100% of my deviance explained. This, of course, makes no sense. If I remove the `s()`, I get more realistic results, but is removing the smoothing function from a GAM appropriate for proper analyses? Is there something I need to change in either my `final.s` or `GAM1` code that helps the smoothing function, `s()`, work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) If you remove smooths from a GAM, you essentially get a GLM. So doing that won't really solve your problem, as your result is indeed strange. 2) What kind of variables are those? Are any of them factors (categorical), or are they all continuous?

Comment: First of all, I think 11 splines is quite a lot! That way you are over specifying your model, as a result you would have a perfect fit. Second, I think you should specify how many points you want to use for each spline, for example: final.s <- pb~s(elev, 10)+s(p_jul,10)

Comment: @Robbie If you don't set `fx = TRUE`, the second parameter (`k`) of `s` indicates the starting value of the basis dimension. mgcv shrinks this dimension through penalized regression. Your value of 10 is probably larger than what is automatically chosen.

Comment: @OP Have you tried setting `select = TRUE` in `gam`? That way some smoothers could be shrunk to zero. Anyway, 11 smoothers is too many if you can support them only with 125 data points. I'd want at least a few thousand data points for such a complex model.

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. @Tilen those variables are all continuous

Comment: Also, @Roland I haven't - trying that right now. I am aware that my dataset is unusually small compared to the number of environmental variables. (Un)fortunately, those 11 variables produce the lowest AIC, and had the highest AUC, when I was selecting for variables compared to models with a smaller number of variables.

Comment: Update: `select = TRUE` produces the same results @Roland

Comment: @Roland and Robbie, I doubt that this is the reason. I have used GAMs with similar numbers of predictors, with similar (and in some cases lower) sample sizes. While I agree with you that too many smooths on small sample size can be problematic, I don't think this is the case here. And I can't see how it could lead to a perfect fit.

Comment: @Tula, can you provide data in the form of a reproducible example?

Comment: @Tilen I'll get a reproducible example out as soon as possible. I'm currently testing something that @Roland pointed out - my sample size is small. I'm currently creating a large number of background data points to stick into my data frame. I'm curious if my small sample size, combined with my many environmental variables, is why `s()` isn't working as it should.

Comment: Some things: fit the model using `method = "REML"`; check the fitted models using `concurvity()`, I suspect many of those variables are quite concurved (nonlinear equiv of collinear); are you seeing a separation issue? with 11 splines of 10 df each you might be able to perfectly predict because you have such flexibility to partition the multivariate space of the data into regions containing only 1s or 0s, not a mix.

Comment: If you are about to add background (pseudo absence) points, you might want to look at recent work of David Warton, Ian Renner, and co in Methods in Ecology and Evolution on approaches that just use the observed presences, i.e. where you encountered something. Making up the 0s is often not a good idea.

Comment: Can you add a figure to the post showing the output from `plot(GAM1, pages = 1, scale = 0)` and the output from `gam.check()` including the 4 plots?